# DotNetBrowser rendering issues on lightweight mode

Tags: wpf, dotnetbrowser

I'm testing DotNetBrowser (version 1.13) with a WPF window where I need to load an specific page ([Comprovante de Situação Cadastral no CPF](https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaSituacao/ConsultaPublica.asp)) and let the user click on a button to save the image from the page.

When I load the site in lightweight mode there is rendering issues in font size and some elements are out of position, but when I load the same page in heavyweight mode it looks fine.

lightweight example
[image]

heavyweight example
[image]

Has anyone experienced this same issue and have a workaround for this?

Using heavyweight mode is not an option due to performance issues and by not having the OnRepaint event.

Comment: https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110001-lightweight-vs-heavyweight

Comment: @CelsoLívero I have seen this article before posting here. I tested the two options and as I pointed out, heavyweight is not a viable option.

Comment: What DotNetBrowser version do you use? Do you have any DPI settings (125%, 150%, etc.)?

Comment: @VladyslavTsvek DotNetBrowser 1.13 and no DPI settings. In the examples I just started a project from scratch with the minimal code to display the browser. If it helps, any page that I tested until now looks fine but this address [Receita Federal](https://www.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Aplicacoes/SSL/ATCTA/CPF/ConsultaSituacao/ConsultaPublica.asp) that is what I need to display.

Comment: Seems that DotNetBrowser has a bug. It will be fixed in one of the next releases.

Comment: I'd like to inform you that this issue has been fixed in DotNetBrowser 1.16.